# calling javascript function before PHP Header

Tags: php, javascript

I am using this code to call a javascript function and then redirect PHP page.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

mixpanel.track('login: Login ', {'page name' : document.title, 'url' : window.location.pathname});
</script>;  

<?php
        header("Location:".$domain_name."/services.htm");

?>
```

But this code is not working, if i don't redirect then js function works fine.

i also tried `ob_start();` and `ob_end_flush();`  but nothing worked. How can use JS function before redirect. i am new to JavaScript and PHP header function.

Comment: That is impossible. Headers must be sent before any output!

Comment: Javascript will **never** run before PHP headers. That's a fundamental misunderstanding of how Javascript/PHP/HTTP works.

Comment: header function sends header to browser. And you want to execute JS before even sending any content to browser!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP runs on the *server* and JavaScript runs in the *browser*.  You can't just mix them together like that.

What you need to do is do the redirect with JavaScript, and not PHP.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    mixpanel.track('login: Login ', {'page name' : document.title, 'url' : window.location.pathname});
    window.location = '<?=$domain_name?>/services.htm';
</script>
```

**UPDATE**:  The redirect is triggering before `mixpanel.track` is complete.  You need to pass a function to the callback <sup>[docs](https://mixpanel.com/docs/integration-libraries/javascript-full-api#track)</sup>, so it runs once it's done.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    mixpanel.track('login: Login ', {
        'page name': document.title,
        'url': window.location.pathname
    }, function(){
        window.location = '<?=$domain_name?>/services.htm';
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This did not worked. its redirecting properly. but mixpanel.track function does not seems to worked. but if i replace insert alert(); after the mixpanel.track function. then both works fine. but alert() is problem that i cant show on my page.

Comment: @Asghar: What is `mixpanel.track`?  My guess is it the page is redirecting before it's finished.

Comment: @Asghar: Why do you want to redirect after this?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: mixpanel is analytics API. i am tracking my user login. when some users logins to my system i track to analytics and the redirect to page that should be shown after user logins.

Answer (score 1):

You should forward your user with javascript as well. Something like `window.location = '<?php echo $domain_name ?>/services.htm';`

Answer (score -1):

You can redirect using Javascript itself after using your function:

```
window.location = 'http://www.example.com';
```

Alternative, you can use [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) based solution; but it has to be combined with `window.location`, where location is given by the php script called by ajax.

Comment: `window.location` isn't a function.